# Getting unmanaged/native C++/CLI class in a DLL into a unmanaged unit test in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio, c++-cli, mstest, unmanaged

Here I am banging my head against the same dang wall so I'm going to ask this question and either get it answered or answer it myself so I can look this up the *next* time.

My example is created from scratch from the built-in templates.  I'm using the MS directions ["Unit testing native code with Test Explorer"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh270864.aspx)

First I create an unmanaged DLL using the templates.  That gives me:

Win32Project1.vcxproj

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" ToolsVersion="12.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ItemGroup Label="ProjectConfigurations">
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Debug|Win32">
      <Configuration>Debug</Configuration>
      <Platform>Win32</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Release|Win32">
      <Configuration>Release</Configuration>
      <Platform>Win32</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
  </ItemGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
    <ProjectGuid>{33455C38-A354-46D1-8883-9292408E03C1}</ProjectGuid>
    <Keyword>Win32Proj</Keyword>
    <RootNamespace>Win32Project1</RootNamespace>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" />
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'" Label="Configuration">
    <ConfigurationType>DynamicLibrary</ConfigurationType>
    <UseDebugLibraries>true</UseDebugLibraries>
    <PlatformToolset>v120</PlatformToolset>
    <CharacterSet>Unicode</CharacterSet>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'" Label="Configuration">
    <ConfigurationType>DynamicLibrary</ConfigurationType>
    <UseDebugLibraries>false</UseDebugLibraries>
    <PlatformToolset>v120</PlatformToolset>
    <WholeProgramOptimization>true</WholeProgramOptimization>
    <CharacterSet>Unicode</CharacterSet>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.props" />
  <ImportGroup Label="ExtensionSettings">
  </ImportGroup>
  <ImportGroup Label="PropertySheets" Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">
    <Import Project="$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props" Condition="exists('$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props')" Label="LocalAppDataPlatform" />
  </ImportGroup>
  <ImportGroup Label="PropertySheets" Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">
    <Import Project="$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props" Condition="exists('$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props')" Label="LocalAppDataPlatform" />
  </ImportGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Label="UserMacros" />
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">
    <LinkIncremental>true</LinkIncremental>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">
    <LinkIncremental>false</LinkIncremental>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">
    <ClCompile>
      <PrecompiledHeader>Use</PrecompiledHeader>
      <WarningLevel>Level3</WarningLevel>
      <Optimization>Disabled</Optimization>
      <PreprocessorDefinitions>WIN32;_DEBUG;_WINDOWS;_USRDLL;WIN32PROJECT1_EXPORTS;%(PreprocessorDefinitions)</PreprocessorDefinitions>
      <SDLCheck>true</SDLCheck>
    </ClCompile>
    <Link>
      <SubSystem>Windows</SubSystem>
      <GenerateDebugInformation>true</GenerateDebugInformation>
    </Link>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>
  <ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">
    <ClCompile>
      <WarningLevel>Level3</WarningLevel>
      <PrecompiledHeader>Use</PrecompiledHeader>
      <Optimization>MaxSpeed</Optimization>
      <FunctionLevelLinking>true</FunctionLevelLinking>
      <IntrinsicFunctions>true</IntrinsicFunctions>
      <PreprocessorDefinitions>WIN32;NDEBUG;_WINDOWS;_USRDLL;WIN32PROJECT1_EXPORTS;%(PreprocessorDefinitions)</PreprocessorDefinitions>
      <SDLCheck>true</SDLCheck>
    </ClCompile>
    <Link>
      <SubSystem>Windows</SubSystem>
      <GenerateDebugInformation>true</GenerateDebugInformation>
      <EnableCOMDATFolding>true</EnableCOMDATFolding>
      <OptimizeReferences>true</OptimizeReferences>
    </Link>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Text Include="ReadMe.txt" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ClInclude Include="stdafx.h" />
    <ClInclude Include="targetver.h" />
    <ClInclude Include="Win32Project1.h" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ClCompile Include="dllmain.cpp">
      <CompileAsManaged Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">false</CompileAsManaged>
      <PrecompiledHeader Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">
      </PrecompiledHeader>
      <CompileAsManaged Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">false</CompileAsManaged>
      <PrecompiledHeader Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">
      </PrecompiledHeader>
    </ClCompile>
    <ClCompile Include="stdafx.cpp">
      <PrecompiledHeader Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">Create</PrecompiledHeader>
      <PrecompiledHeader Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">Create</PrecompiledHeader>
    </ClCompile>
    <ClCompile Include="Win32Project1.cpp" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.targets" />
  <ImportGroup Label="ExtensionTargets">
  </ImportGroup>
</Project>
```

Win32Project1.h

```
#ifdef WIN32PROJECT1_EXPORTS
#define WIN32PROJECT1_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define WIN32PROJECT1_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

// This class is exported from the Win32Project1.dll
class WIN32PROJECT1_API CWin32Project1 {
public:
    CWin32Project1(void);

    bool Foo();
};

extern WIN32PROJECT1_API int nWin32Project1;

WIN32PROJECT1_API int fnWin32Project1(void);
```

Win32Project1.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Win32Project1.h"


// This is an example of an exported variable
WIN32PROJECT1_API int nWin32Project1=0;

// This is an example of an exported function.
WIN32PROJECT1_API int fnWin32Project1(void)
{
    return 42;
}

// This is the constructor of a class that has been exported.
// see Win32Project1.h for the class definition
CWin32Project1::CWin32Project1()
{
    return;
}

bool CWin32Project1::Foo() {return true;}
```

Then I create an unmanaged unit test project from the templates and add a unit test.

UnitTest1.vcxproj

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" ToolsVersion="12.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ItemGroup Label="ProjectConfigurations">
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Debug|Win32">
      <Configuration>Debug</Configuration>
      <Platform>Win32</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Release|Win32">
      <Configuration>Release</Configuration>
      <Platform>Win32</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
  </ItemGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
    <ProjectGuid>{B149C359-4E44-4B7E-B3B9-F682865D0AE2}</ProjectGuid>
    <Keyword>Win32Proj</Keyword>
    <RootNamespace>UnitTest1</RootNamespace>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" />
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'" Label="Configuration">
    <ConfigurationType>DynamicLibrary</ConfigurationType>
    <UseDebugLibraries>true</UseDebugLibraries>
    <PlatformToolset>v120</PlatformToolset>
    <CharacterSet>Unicode</CharacterSet>
    <UseOfMfc>false</UseOfMfc>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'" Label="Configuration">
    <ConfigurationType>DynamicLibrary</ConfigurationType>
    <UseDebugLibraries>false</UseDebugLibraries>
    <PlatformToolset>v120</PlatformToolset>
    <WholeProgramOptimization>true</WholeProgramOptimization>
    <CharacterSet>Unicode</CharacterSet>
    <UseOfMfc>false</UseOfMfc>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.props" />
  <ImportGroup Label="ExtensionSettings">
  </ImportGroup>
  <ImportGroup Label="PropertySheets" Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">
    <Import Project="$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props" Condition="exists('$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props')" Label="LocalAppDataPlatform" />
  </ImportGroup>
  <ImportGroup Label="PropertySheets" Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">
    <Import Project="$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props" Condition="exists('$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props')" Label="LocalAppDataPlatform" />
  </ImportGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Label="UserMacros" />
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">
    <LinkIncremental>true</LinkIncremental>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">
    <LinkIncremental>true</LinkIncremental>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">
    <ClCompile>
      <PrecompiledHeader>Use</PrecompiledHeader>
      <WarningLevel>Level3</WarningLevel>
      <Optimization>Disabled</Optimization>
      <AdditionalIncludeDirectories>$(VCInstallDir)UnitTest\include;%(AdditionalIncludeDirectories)</AdditionalIncludeDirectories>
      <PreprocessorDefinitions>WIN32;_DEBUG;%(PreprocessorDefinitions)</PreprocessorDefinitions>
      <UseFullPaths>true</UseFullPaths>
    </ClCompile>
    <Link>
      <SubSystem>Windows</SubSystem>
      <GenerateDebugInformation>true</GenerateDebugInformation>
      <AdditionalLibraryDirectories>$(VCInstallDir)UnitTest\lib;%(AdditionalLibraryDirectories)</AdditionalLibraryDirectories>
    </Link>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>
  <ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">
    <ClCompile>
      <WarningLevel>Level3</WarningLevel>
      <PrecompiledHeader>Use</PrecompiledHeader>
      <Optimization>MaxSpeed</Optimization>
      <FunctionLevelLinking>true</FunctionLevelLinking>
      <IntrinsicFunctions>true</IntrinsicFunctions>
      <AdditionalIncludeDirectories>$(VCInstallDir)UnitTest\include;%(AdditionalIncludeDirectories)</AdditionalIncludeDirectories>
      <PreprocessorDefinitions>WIN32;NDEBUG;%(PreprocessorDefinitions)</PreprocessorDefinitions>
      <UseFullPaths>true</UseFullPaths>
    </ClCompile>
    <Link>
      <SubSystem>Windows</SubSystem>
      <GenerateDebugInformation>true</GenerateDebugInformation>
      <EnableCOMDATFolding>true</EnableCOMDATFolding>
      <OptimizeReferences>true</OptimizeReferences>
      <AdditionalLibraryDirectories>$(VCInstallDir)UnitTest\lib;%(AdditionalLibraryDirectories)</AdditionalLibraryDirectories>
    </Link>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ClInclude Include="stdafx.h" />
    <ClInclude Include="targetver.h" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ClCompile Include="stdafx.cpp">
      <PrecompiledHeader Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">Create</PrecompiledHeader>
      <PrecompiledHeader Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">Create</PrecompiledHeader>
    </ClCompile>
    <ClCompile Include="unittest1.cpp" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.targets" />
  <ImportGroup Label="ExtensionTargets">
  </ImportGroup>
</Project>
```

UnitTest1.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "CppUnitTest.h"
#include "..\Win32Project1\Win32Project1.h"

using namespace Microsoft::VisualStudio::CppUnitTestFramework;

namespace UnitTest1
{       
    TEST_CLASS(UnitTest1)
    {
    public:

        TEST_METHOD(TestMethod1)
        {
            auto bar = new CWin32Project1();
            Assert::AreEqual(true, bar->Foo());
        }

    };
}
```

When I compile this, I get the errors:

```
1>unittest1.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall CWin32Project1::CWin32Project1(void)" (__imp_??0CWin32Project1@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall UnitTest1::UnitTest1::TestMethod1(void)" (?TestMethod1@UnitTest1@1@QAEXXZ)
1>unittest1.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: bool __thiscall CWin32Project1::Foo(void)" (__imp_?Foo@CWin32Project1@@QAE_NXZ) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall UnitTest1::UnitTest1::TestMethod1(void)" (?TestMethod1@UnitTest1@1@QAEXXZ)
```

What is the problem here?

Comment: You did not tell the linker that it also needs to link the Win32Project1.lib file.  So it can never find the CWin32Project1 class member definitions, just like it told you.

Comment: Question is not *exact* duplicate.  Answers vary sufficiently that solution is not readily apparent.  Trying to put this question and answer as an answer to referenced question gets downvoted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UnitTest1.vcxproj needs the following changes:

```
  <AdditionalLibraryDirectories>$(SolutionDir)Debug;$(VCInstallDir)UnitTest\lib;%(AdditionalLibraryDirectories)</AdditionalLibraryDirectories>
  <AdditionalDependencies>Win32Project1.lib;%(AdditionalDependencies)</AdditionalDependencies>
```